# VB random function returns same value twice

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

```
Dim top = RandomPosition()
Dim left = RandomPosition()    
End Sub

Function RandomPosition()
    Dim rand As New Random()
    Dim number = rand.Next(1, 100)
    Return number
End Function
```

Hi guys I am trying to get 2 different random values (for now. Once this works I will need a few more). The problem is that with the above code `top` and `left` always equal the same random number.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Duplicate Random Numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769061/getting-duplicate-random-numbers)

Comment: The answers you've got address your specific problem, but be aware that even once you've fixed it, you might still *sometimes* get the same number twice in a row. Sometimes when you roll a die you get a `5` and then another `5`, after all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create a *new* random sequence every time you call `RandomPosition` but, because you're calling it in quick succession, they'll have the same seed (based on time). Same seed means same sequence.

You should create the `rand` variable once, then just continue to use it, something like:

```
Dim rand as New Random()
Dim top = rand.Next (1, 100)
Dim left = rand.Next (1, 100)
```

Alternatively, if you *really* want it in its own function, make the random generator static so that it maintains its state across calls:

```
Function RandomPosition()
    Static rand = New Random()
    Return rand.Next(1, 100)
End Function
```

The following complete VB2010 program shows this in action:

```
Module Module1
    Function RandomPosition()
        Static rand As Random = New Random()
        Return rand.Next(1, 100)
    End Function

    Sub Main()
        Dim top = RandomPosition()
        Dim left = RandomPosition()
        MsgBox("top = " & CStr(top) & ", left = " & CStr(left))
    End Sub
End Module
```

It outputs, on various runs:

```
top = 7, left = 93
top = 45, left = 90
top = 44, left = 62
```

Answer (score 0):

how about making an instance `static` to preserve the same instance?

```
Public Function RandomPosition(r) As Integer
    Static rand As System.Random = New System.Random()
    Return rand.Next(1, 100)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wait 1 millisecond before initialising the Random object.

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
Dim rand As New System.Random
```