# Generate a random boolean

Tags: vb.net, random

I am a little stuck with a simple Question: how to generate a simple random Boolean?
If am correct, a `Boolean 0 = false and 1 = true`, but how to suse that?

Current code:

```
Dim RandGen As New Random
Dim RandBool As Boolean
RandBool = Boolean.Parse(RandGen.Next(0, 1).tostring)
```

Comment: Generate a random number, multiply it by 2 and round down?
`CInt(Math.Floor(Rnd() * 2))` should produce 0 or 1 which you could then use

Comment: Also, see this previously asked question: [Random Int in VB.Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676/random-int-in-vb-net)

Comment: Dudledok it does work - but how does it work? Especially the multiplication with two is surprising for me.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Or just simply:

```c#
Random rng = new Random();
bool randomBool = rng.Next(0, 2) > 0;
```

Saves some processing power of parsing text, whereas a simple compare is enough.

Edit: Second parameter is exclusive, so should be `.Next(0, 2)`.

Comment: That is neat, I will go with it, thanks.
How does it work? Does it round the resultung random number to 0 / 1 and then tests if the value is greater than 0?

Comment: It generates either an integer 0 or 1. This number is checked if it is larger than zero. If it is, then it returns `true`, otherwise `false`. It's actually just in inline if-statement. Since the actual number generator already generates a 50% chance of being zero or one, it just need to be mapped from `[0,1]` to `[false,true]`.

Comment: The first parameter of 0 is optional because that is the default. `rng.Next(2) > 0` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Dim RandGen As New Random

```
    Dim RandBool As Boolean

    RandBool = RandGen.Next(0, 2).ToString

    TextBox1.Text = RandBool
```

Comment: Does that mean that we can assign a string value to a variable of type Booelan, in VB.NET?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
        string[] trueOrFalse = { "false", "true"};
        bool RandBool = bool.Parse(trueOrFalse[RandGen.Next(0,2)]);
```

Comment: Good idea, but why declare your array as a string array instead of a boolean array? You have one extra not necessary step.