# select random from target string VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

how could i make that

Source_Source.Text (richtextbox) :

> `src="test.com"` akalsjdjalksdv `src="another.com"` asdbnmslkbjcxv 
>   asdas as danms d amsn asdasd `src="cold.com"`asdas as dasd amnbs dma d  sdf kjhds f `src="find.com"` asd kja sdasjhk d asd`src="other.com"` a jksdh asksjd hasdjh `src="found.com"`

what if i wanna get random src=" ", for example, if i clicked butten will show message =  `src="test.com"` , another time if i clicked button will show another random, for example `src="another.com"` ,

my currently code only select first string which = `src="test.com"` , and i wanna select randoms `src="[random test / cold / other / found / find]"`

for example my next click can show message for `src="find.com"` that for example.

my code :

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim sSource As String = Source_Source.Text 'String that is being searched
    Dim sDelimStart As String = Search_1.Text 'First delimiting word
    Dim sDelimEnd As String = Search_2.Text  'Second delimiting word
    Dim nIndexStart As Integer = sSource.IndexOf(sDelimStart) 'Find the first occurrence of f1
    Dim nIndexEnd As Integer = sSource.IndexOf(sDelimEnd, nIndexStart + sDelimStart.Length + 1) 'Find the first occurrence of f2

    If nIndexStart > -1 AndAlso nIndexEnd > -1 Then '-1 means the word was not found.
        Dim res As String = Strings.Mid(sSource, nIndexStart + sDelimStart.Length + 1, nIndexEnd - nIndexStart - sDelimStart.Length) 'Crop the text between
         MessageBox.Show(res) 'Display
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("One or both of the delimiting words were not found!")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Function RndUrl() As String
    Dim UrlStr() As String = {"whatever.com", "whatever2.com"}
    Return Rand.Next(0, UrlStr.Length) '"Rand" Declared at Class scope as Random
End Function
```

Usage:

```
    TextBox1.Text = "src=""" & RndUrl() & ""
```

Comment: Error :  'Rand' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: declare it as Public Shared

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking for a certain phrase in a String?  If so look into String.Contains() method.
For example:

```
If Source_Source.Text.Contains(Search_1.Text) Then
    ' Do you're logic here if found
    Source_Source.Text.SubString(0, 5) ' Or where ever that part of the string is that you want.
End If
```

Comment: let me clear it more, if i wanna get random link from webpage source and its start daily with [src="], and put it in richtextbox so now i wanna get random src links that found , with every click.

Comment: Give this link a shot. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15484742/generate-random-string)  It uses the Random class.