# How to randomly choose 0 or 1 vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to make a generator that will show results in text box , i want it to randomly choose  0 or 1 , how can i make that ?

Kode that works :

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Dim r as New Random()
Dim n As Integer = r.Next(2)
TextBox1.Text = CStr(n) 

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What does "between 0 and 1" mean? Do you mean "either 0 or 1 randomly"? Or "a value >= 0.0 and <= 1.0"?

Comment: Then please [edit] your question and make it clear that you want to "randomly select either 0 or 1", so we know what you're asking. (And for future reference: We can't see your screen or read your mind, so you need to be **specific** when you ask your question. If we can't understand what you're asking, we can't help you find an answer.)

Comment: You can see examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676/random-int-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
Dim r as New Random()
Dim n As Integer = r.Next(2)
TextBox1.Text = CStr(n)
```

Comment: @NemanjaVukmirovic - I'm consused -- isn't that the same as what you posted?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway he updated the question to have my code sample shortly after I answered

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Random class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) included in the .NET Framework. It has an instance method on it called [Next](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which take in a min/max value. Here's an example:

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim rng As Random = New Random()
    Dim randomNumber As Integer = rng.Next(0,2)
    ' Do what you want with randomNumber from here...
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Yes i did try the edited solution , it just sends 0 :/

Comment: Did you run it multiple times? `rng.Next(0,2)` is a random selection of 0 and 1, like flipping a coin. You could get zero quite a few times before a one shows up in the RNG.

Comment: Just for some clarification, the minimum value in Next is _inclusive_, but the maximum value is _exclusive_, meaning `rng.Next(0,2)` will only possibly return 0 or 1