# Creating a button that changes Label ForeColor with each click

Tags: vb.net, button, colors, label

Here's what I'm trying to do. I have a label named "lblWelcome", and a button named "btnTextColor". What I want the button to do is change the labels forecolor each time the button is clicked. Each time the button is pressed the forecolor of the label will change to a **different** color than before. That is what I want.

Here is what I've tried. Side note: I only put Red, Blue, and Black just as a start, so I could try the button and see if it works. My first hope was to get the button to choose a random color each time it's clicked. That would be perfect. Otherwise, just going through a list of colors one by one would be fine as well.

```
Private Sub btnTextColor_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTextColor.Click
    lblWelcome.ForeColor = Color.Red
    lblWelcome.ForeColor = Color.Blue
    lblWelcome.ForeColor = Color.Black

End Sub
```

With the above code, when I run the program, the button changes the labels forecolor to black. It just follows the last line of code. So, I went to the internets, looked for a solution, some bit of code I'm missing here. I found something called a "string", but it wasn't in reference to forecolor and I wasn't sure what to think or do. I'm just kind of stuck, I need to know what to add to make this button work the way I intended it to. But *most* importantly, I want to know how the solution I find works. For example, when someone tells me what to type, I'll fix my button, but I haven't learned the meaning of what I typed. I want to learn. So please, explain it a little bit when you reply to this. Just a little bit, that's all I ask. What command am I looking for? How do I use it? What does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
Private Sub btnTextColor_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnTextColor.Click
    Static m_Rnd As New Random
    lblWelcome.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, m_Rnd.Next(0, 255), m_Rnd.Next(0, 255), m_Rnd.Next(0, 255))
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you tell me what "Static" does? And m_Rnd? And Color.FromArgb?
I want to know what I'm doing, so I can use them again if I need to.

Comment: From the MSDN - [Static](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2cty7t8.aspx), [Color.FromArgb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cce5h557%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), `m_Rnd` is just a variable. Not trying to be rude at all, but the MSDN has all the answers you need.

Comment: As to why the random number generator is declared as Static, see the second answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676/random-int-in-vb-net).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I appreciate it greatly. I'll look into finding out what each thing I'm typing means on MSDN. Currently reading [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2cty7t8.aspx) article. Thanks again for the assistance. :)

Answer (score -2):

```
Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click
     Dim mybrush = Brushes.Black
    Dim cDialog As New ColorDialog()
    cDialog.Color = Label1.BackColor ' initial selection is current color.

    If (cDialog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then
        Label1.BackColor = cDialog.Color ' update with user selected color.
    End If


End Sub
```

hope this helps as a second option

Comment: Does this do the same thing as the other suggestion? Changes the labels color to a random color? I don't understand why two different codes would do the same thing. If anyone wants to explain exactly what these codes do step by step, I would greatly appreciate it. I'm trying to learn as much as I can. That way I can type my own code, and  so I can answer questions for others by showing them what to do. I don't know what Dim does, what mybrush means, what Brushes.Black does, what ColorDialog() means, or what As New does. And I'm trying to learn. On MSDN the definitions are still complicated.

Comment: it does exactly the same but you can see all see the colour chart ,before you pick a color,,run to see for yourself.... so.keyword''' dim'' tells the computer you are about to 'declare' a 'variable',, a variable is piece of storage in the computer where you will store a  value ,,in this case variable is  called my brush ....you can call the variable anything u desire, instead you create a variable name that makes sense, that's why you write ,,dim mybrush = brushes.black ..brushes .black is predefined.http://www.vbtutor.net/vb2008book/vb2008me_preview.pdf

Comment: Thank you so much for that Barry. I appreciate it. :)

I have another question if you want to give it a go.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28551160/how-to-create-a-custom-button-specifically-the-exact-button-from-facebook-sign