# How to create a custom button, specifically the exact button from Facebook sign up

Tags: facebook, button

First of all, go to [Facebook](http://www.facebook.com/). Then make sure you're not logged in. When you log out of Facebook it will bring you to the log in/sign up page. At the bottom of the Sign Up section, after the user has filled out their information, there is a green button with rounded edges that says "Sign Up".

What I want is to create that exact button on my form in Visual Basic. I've been trying to create a form that looks almost exactly like the Facebook sign up page, just a little different. I have a lot to do still. But so far, this is what I have: http://tinypic.com/r/2zz1cwm/8 (Sorry I can't upload pictures in my posts here yet, requires 10 reputation points. Soon enough though. For now, I have to upload the pictures to tinypic, then get the url and post it here.)

The button I made was very difficult for me to make, I had to go on YouTube to find out how to make a rounded button, and it looks **horrible**, absolutely horrible. I cannot use a button looking like that. You can see the pixels! :(

So what I'm trying to learn is how to make a button that looks exactly like the Facebook sign up button. Any suggestions? And please, don't just give me the code to do it. Explain it a little so I know what I'm doing exactly. I don't want to just take code and put it in my program and be done with it. I want to know what I'm doing. Thank you very much for reading my question and for lending a hand. I appreciate any and all help. Have a wonderful day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own problem.

Use a picture box instead of a button. Double click the picture box and add the code as if you were for a button. For example, when you click my picture box it opens form2. Because I put `form2.show()` in the button_click section.

Hooray for figuring it out on my own! Took me long enough. Two days..

Answer (score 0):

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?611776-RESOLVED-round-button. hope this helps you out . you should download a few vb pdf's from google that will help you a lot to get the basics .

Comment: hey Ryan sorry you haven't got much help yet ,I am sure so will help soon , I tried this on my computer , and what I did was drag a button to form . I searched google for Facebook sign up button, save it to computer ,import the  Facebook picture of the button from your pc,  click project , then resources , add existing file , find the picture ,save to the vb resources , and make the picture the back round image of the button by going to properties of the button select button image back round, select the image, I set it to stretch image ,double click button that's where you put all the code ,

Comment: I figured it out. You are pretty much right Barry. What I did was I took two pictures of the Facebook button, one with the mouse over it, one without, because it changes on mouse over. Then I made a picture box, set the first picture as the image for it, and then added some code to make the image change on mouse over. Anyways, moral of the story is.... **If you want a custom button image, you have to use a picture box rather than a button.**