# How do I create a random number generator in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, random

Hi i want to make a random number generator that just creates random expressions

This is for a math game project i have. My problem is that right now i dont understand the random generator.

Like i just want it to create a random 2 digit integer then an operation then another random 2 digit integer. One random expression generator will generate subtraction and addition problems, while another will generate multiplication and division problem

like this

23 - 78
48-55
24 + 16

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random Int in VB.Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676/random-int-in-vb-net)

Comment: SO isn't a code writing service. You need to have a go at writing your own code and when you get stuck then ask a question here and include your code in the question.

Comment: You make it sound like i haven't tried my own code, when in fact i did, problem is that it was just rubbish to begin with. There was no point posting my code here cause it was broken and wrong

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the `Random` class would be useful:

```
Sub Main

    'Create an instance of the Random class
    Dim rnd As New Random()

    'Get a random number from 10 to 99  (2 digits)
    Dim randomNumber As Integer = rnd.Next(10, 100)

    Console.WriteLine(randomNumber)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably going to find it easier to figure out how the current generator works than writing your own.

There is an expression that will give you a random integer between two inclusive bounds:

```
value = CInt(Math.Floor((upper - lower + 1) * Rnd())) + lower
```

and you can use that to get your two-digit numbers:

```
value = CInt(Math.Floor(90 * Rnd())) + 10
```

To get a basic operation from the set of four `{+-*/}`, you can use the same rules to give you a random value from zero to three inclusive:

```
op = CInt(Math.Floor(4 * Rnd()))
```

If you want a *textual* representation of that, you simply need a string that you can get the operator from (as character or string), something like:

```
Dim ops As String = "+-*/"
Dim chrop as Char = ops(CInt(Math.Floor(4 * Rnd())))
Dim strop as String = ops.SubString(CInt(Math.Floor(4 * Rnd())),1)
```

---

Here, for example, is a complete program to generate such expressions, though you'll need to figure out how to integrate that with your own code (refactoring it into a couple of functions would be nice for a start).

And I haven't done an *exhaustive* analysis on whether there are edge cases in the number generation so you'll need a test suite to be certain.

All things you should be doing as a developer anyway :-)

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim ops As String = "+-*/"
        Randomize()
        Dim value1 As Integer = CInt(Math.Floor(90 * Rnd())) + 10
        Dim value2 As Integer = CInt(Math.Floor(90 * Rnd())) + 10
        Dim strop As String = ops.Substring(CInt(Math.Floor(4 * Rnd())), 1)
        Console.WriteLine(value1 & " " & strop & " " & value2)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: One last clarification how would I make this module create the random number generation in a texbox ? would i just add a 

Textbox1.text = (value1 & " " & strop & " " & value2)

sorry i have to ask you, i have limited vb.net accessibility and my last project making session is on friday. I have no other chances to test it

Comment: It seems like the built in Random class would be much easier to read and understand than the old `Rnd()` function.