# How to Choose Random number from given list of numbers in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I want to create a random number generator in VB.NET ***But*** from my own given list of numbers

> **Like Chose random numbers from [1,2,3,4,5,6] e.t.c**

Comment: **XY Question Revealed!:** `I want to create a Serial Key Generator`  A good serial number generator is not going to be based on random values.  Random does not mean unique.  For a serial number or key, you should hash something that identifies whatever you are registering and encode bytes from that - either Hex or a Base26 converter to give you results like `FKWF9-6LX4F-4RQ6Q-QD76D-3VYVR`.  Deterministic GUID are also great, but the output is less user friendly.

Answer (score 3):

This is how you get a random natural number in the interval of [0, n - 1]:

```
CInt(Rnd() * n)
```

Let's suppose you have a `List` of `n` elements. This is how you get a random element from it:

```
MyList(CInt(Rnd() * n))
```

Comment: Can You please explain some details LIKE  from "123-123-123" and "234-234-234"

Comment: @AliAhmad you have a list of items. There are n items in your list. If you randomize a natural number between 0 and n - 1, then you get a number, i, where 0 <= i <= n - 1. This number should be the index you will use to get the value from your list.

Comment: > Can you please Answer this Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41540643/how-to-get-a-text-after-certain-text-in-vb-net

Comment: @AliAhmad I will take a look at it. If this answer helped you with your question, then you might consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark.

Comment: Your question is not clear. You have a text, but where is that text? In a file? In a String?

Answer (score 3):

Already built into .NET base of 'Random' and then extending that into your existing choices.  This is NOT the same as generating the number from a Random as you are specifying YOUR OWN list first and then merely getting positioning with the help of a new Rand and using your length as a ceiling for it.

```
 Sub Main()
    'Say you have four items in your list
    Dim ls = New List(Of Integer)({1, 4, 8, 20})
    'I can find the 'position' of where the count of my array could be
    Dim rand = New Random().Next(0, ls.Count)
    'This will give a different 'position' every time.
    Console.WriteLine(ls(rand))

    Console.ReadLine()
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a random number generator to generate a random number in the range of the list/array length, then use the result to point to the index of your number list.

```
Dim numbers As Integer() = New Integer() {1,2,5,6,7,8,12,43,56,67}

Dim randomKey = numbers(CInt(Rnd() * numbers.length))
```

***Edited** based on Lajos Arpad's answer of how to get the random number

Comment: I want to create a Serial Key Generator from my Own Serial Keys List

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function you can try, see more here [Random integer in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676/random-integer-in-vb-net)

```
Public Function GetRandom(ByVal Min As Integer, ByVal Max As Integer) As    Integer
Dim Generator As System.Random = New System.Random()
Return Generator.Next(Min, Max + 1)
End Function
```

Comment: I want to Choose from [abc-abc-abc-abc] and [cde-cde-cde-cde] Randomly

Comment: That should actually be Generator.Next(Min, Max + 1).  The maximum value passed to .Next is not inclusive.

Comment: Gordon, Thanks, Add +1 to the code. Ali, you can use this to generate random number -1 and use it as index to your array.

Comment: I don't want to generate a random number but I want to choose random from my own list LIKE from "123-123-123" and "999-999-999"

Comment: Why not put your item into an array?

Comment: Thank You Tony Dong | I got it